# Could audio line-out (from a PC) be used to flash an Atmel or PIC?

Tags: power

First question is probably how much power can standard PC line-out provide?

Unfortunately I can't seem to find it easily via Google yet, or how to calculate it and from what.

Otherwise, are there any more or less obvious arguments against, that I don't realize being an electronics newbie?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: A similar thing has been done with an arduino. However, if I understand right there was a bootloader present which interpreted the audio and then programmed the device: http://hackaday.com/2011/12/30/programming-an-arduino-using-an-audio-file/

Comment: Lack of bootloaders ("chicken and egg problem") on generic DIP-packaged microcontrollers is the problem I'd like to work around. And I'm interested in avoiding an Arduino inbetween (I already learned Arduino can be used as a programmer).

Comment: If you have MOSFETs, the power output isn't very important. You could definitely use audio line out to drive a MOSFET, but you'd need to have some way of removing the negative part of the sine wave if you're going to use audio. However, we'd need a MOSFET that can turn on at low voltage (was the computer audio 1 V RMS?). That could be solved with a more complex circuit that would use some amplification to drive the MOSFET. Maybe a real audio amplifier? (But than again if you get a real amplifier, you could use pretty much anything).

Comment: Also whatever you decide to do, it's going to be a bit complicated to make a program that will produce correct audio in order to program the microcontroller and that will also depend on the circuit you use on the other side.The most important part which I see now is how complicated the hardware programmer is going to be? It's main competitors are going to be USB to RS-232 chips, so it would need to be simpler or cheaper than the competition.

Comment: Even if you could make the audio outputs work, that won't be easy software to write.  Is all that really worth saving $20?

Comment: I can write the software, if this project can be fruitful. :-)

Comment: @AndrejaKo - I believe your comments are the most concrete and informative as of now, thanks a lot! If you cared to move them into an "answer", I could probably "accept" it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I like your question, and I bet if one is allowed to use some simple external parts (like a diode for example) this might well be possible. Of course one might have to spend hundreds of hours to get a working prototype.

As others have indicated, if it is just for your personal use then you are much better off just spending a few bucks and buying a programmer.

If on the other hand you are looking to make a contribution to the open hardware movement a solution like this could potentially save thousands of people from having to buy a programmer. Possibly this would justify spending hundreds of hours of your time.

Comment: "A few simple external parts" is expected, although they'd need to really be *simple* :D That said, I still don't understand where would the actual difficulty lie? As I understand, line out produces some signal described in WAV file -- so if I put in the WAV some square wave, then push it to a leg of the microcontroller, what can go wrong? :) -> I'd be very grateful if you cared to expand your answer in this direction!

Comment: Your sound card _may_ be able to generate a square wave, but then again some sound cards may be capacitively coupled. If you have 2 PCs download Winscope (free) and run it on a second PC to see what the output of the first looks like. http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/Prac/winscope.htm

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually it can be done, but you would need a fair amount of processing between the oaudio out and the pins of the microcontroller. And by far the easiest way to provide that processing would be in a (programmed!) microcontroller. I guess you would still need some power source, as the amount of power that can reliably be obtained from the audio output is rather small and the voltage is likely to be inconveniently low. And it would be a one-way communication, so no way for the programmer to let you know whether the programming process was succesfull (unless you want to use the microphone input als a back channel). So if your aim is to provide a low-hassle way to program an AVR I guess the answer is simply NO. Better find a PC with a serial or parallel port.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work. Line out is a single signal. You need at least data and a clock (2 signals) to program a part.

Comment: I thought line-outs had left and right.

Comment: Huh, *I* did *not* think, but I'm grateful @Kellenjb thought for me :D